# Calling a method on a parent for child objects with a different amount of parameters

Tags: c#, inheritance, parameters

Good day everyone!

Imagine you have this:

```
public abstract class CommandParent
{
    public abstract void Execute();
}

public class Command1 : CommandParent
{
    public override void Execute(){}
}
```

I would like to call the Execute() method for all CommandParent objects, like this:

```
List<CommandParent> _commandList = new List<CommandParent>();
for (int i = 0; i < _commandList.length; i++)
{
    _commandList[i].Execute(); 
}
```

But what if I have another class deriving from CommandParent which has an Execute() method, but with parameters? I would do this,

```
public class Command2 : CommandParent
{
    public override void Execute(string parameter){}
}
```

But then the lines

```
for (int i = 0; i < _commandList.length; i++)
{
    _commandList[i].Execute(); 
}
```

Won't work anymore.
Can this be achieved with a different approach, and if so, how exactly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How would you be able to override the Execute method (with parameters) when the method is not part of the parent CommandParent class? You would get a compile error in Command2 class. You cannot directly call the methods by Class name which are not static.

Comment: Interfaces are your friend here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing doesn't make sense.

`Command2` is explicitly designed to **require** a string parameter on its `Execute` method, and then you intend to call it without that required parameter. That's a clear contradiction of intentions.

If you don't supply the string parameter, how can your code ever receive this string value? If the string value isn't necessary for the code to work, then why would you add this string parameter to begin with?

---

> Hmmm, so it's not possible to have a Command1 class with an Execute() method and a Command2 class with an Execute(string parameter) method and call both methods with a single statement from the parent class?

There are ways to do this, but they are more complex to implement.

**1**

If all commands take *some* kind of input, you can make your base class generic so it specifies the input parameter:

```
public class Command<TExecuteInput>
{
    public abstract void Execute(TExecuteInput input);
}
```

*This could also be an interface with a generic type. It depends on whether you need this class to contain more logic than my example.*

Then all derived classes will get to choose the type of their input parameter:

```
public class StringCommand : Command<string>
{
    public void Execute(string input)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

But having a generic base class is going to complicate your polymorphism if you intend to e.g. store all kinds of commands in a single list and execute them indiscriminately.

This again becomes a matter of contradicting expectations: you require commands to require specific (and varying) types of input, and then you intend to use them in a context where you don't know what input they need and attempt to call them without providing that input.

**2**

You can use the constructor for different initialisation logic. This applies mostly if your command has a reasonably short lifespan.

```
public class Command
{
    public virtual void Execute()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("base command handling");
    }
}

public class StringCommand : Command
{
    public StringCommand(string input)
    {
        this.input = input;
    }

    private readonly string input;

    public override void Execute()
    {
        base.Execute();

        Console.WriteLine($"String command handling: {input}");
    }
}
```

Whether you call `base.Execute()` or not is up to you.

When you take this approach, be very aware of [LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) and its violations. It's fairly common to slip up here and extend your classes in a way that they can no longer be substituted - which you should avoid.

Answer (score 0):

In order to override a method, it must have the same signature as in the base class. Signature means the name of the method and the arguments of the method. So it's not possible to add arguments in your derived class. A workaround that might help you is the following concept with overload and a default parameter:

```
public class Command2 : CommandParent
{
    public override void Execute()
    {
    Execute("default parameter");
    }

    public void Execute(string parameter)
    {
      //your implementation
    }
}
```

As an alternative, you could add the parameter to your base class. It would become

```
public abstract class CommandParent
{
    public abstract void Execute(string parameter);
}
```

and your implementation in `Command1` simply ignores the argument.

Comment: Hmmm, so it's not possible to have a Command1 class with an Execute() method and a Command2 class with an Execute(string parameter) method and call both methods with a single statement from the parent class? The reason I want to avoid your given example is that Command1 and Command2 would then both have 2 signatures for the Execute() method, but only 1 of those needs to be implemented for each class.

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't really understand what you want to do. I edited my answer and provided an alternative. I hope that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to call `command.Execute()` where `command` is of type `CommandParent` and holds a reference to an instance of `Command2`.

```
CommandParent command = new Command2();
command.Execute();
```

If we assume the compiler calls `Command2.Execute(string)`, what would the expected semantics of this be? You're not providing an argument for a required parameter, what happens? A `null` reference is passed? A `default` value? The runtime crashes? The compiler doesn't know, the CLR doesn't know, only you, the programmer, might possibly know what you actually want. So you need to explicitly say what you want:

```
public class Command2 : CommandParent
{
    public override void Execute() => Execute(""); 
    // Or Execute(null), or any other default value you want.

    public void Execute(string parameter)
    {
        // impl...
    }
}
```

If there is no sensible default value for `Execute` in the context of `Command2`, then maybe the `CommandParent` base is not well-designed, since it enforces that the deriving types enable a call to `Execute` with no parameters. If you want the method to accept any number of parameters and then parse them at runtime with the cost of static safety, maybe you want the virtual method to have a signature of `Execute(params object[] parameters)`?

Comment: Actually, what I want to be able to do is have a list or array of CommandParent objects, and call Execute() for each object in that list, with some of the objects being Command1 objects and some of the objects being Command2 objects.

Comment: @Thrindil And what would you expect to happen when argumentless `Execute` call gets dispatched to `Command2.Execute(string)`?

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't compile for multiple reasons.

1/ Command2 doesn't implement Execute() which as been marked as abstract in the base class and must be implemented by all child class

2/ The method  Execute(string parameter) doesn't exist in the base class, so it cannot be overriden by the child class.

The C# compiler identifies methods based on their signatures (method name + type of parameters). So even if Execute() and Execute(string parameter) share the same name, they are 2 distincts methods from the compiler point of view. Since the method Execute(string parameter) doesn't exist in the base class, you cannot override in the child class.

One solution could be:

```
  public abstract class CommandParent
    {
        public abstract void Execute();

        public virtual void Execute(string parameter) {
            Execute();
        }
    }

    public class Command1 : CommandParent
    {
        public override void Execute() { }
    }

    public class Command2 : CommandParent
    {

        public override void Execute() { }
        public override void Execute(string parameter) {
           base.Execute(parameter);
        }
    }
```

Please note that Execute(String parameter) being marked as virtual, it doesn't have to be implemented by all child class.
Also, you can use the prefix "base." in order to explicitly refers to the base class.